# window.rootViewController is not the current view controller

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to setup my app to support push notifications and I have everything working for when the app is opened from a push notification, but now I'm trying to add to show an alert if the app is open and a notification is received.

So far, I have the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println("Received alert and opened it")
    debugPrintln(userInfo)
    if let tripId = (userInfo["trip"] as? String)?.toInt() {
      if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active { // App in foreground
        openTripFromForeground(tripId, type: userInfo["type"] as! String)
      } else { // App in background
        openTripFromBackground(tripId, type: userInfo["type"] as! String)
      }
    }
  }

  func openTripFromForeground(tripId: Int, type: String) {
    var alertController: UIAlertController!
    switch(type) {
      case "new":
        alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New trip", message: "You've been assigned to trip \(tripId).", preferredStyle: .Alert)
      case "changed":
        alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Changed trip", message: "Trip \(tripId) has changed.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
      case "removed":
        alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Removed from trip", message: "Trip \(tripId) has been removed.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
      default:
        println("Trip did something")
        return
    }
    if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController {
      debugPrintln(rootViewController)
      rootViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```

To read about how the application's story board is constructed, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400105/open-notification-to-specific-view) and [this screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s21/sh/1f04b3ac-73e1-4ec6-91ac-a6d1986f8c5f/017295b1fd4c9c1c).

When the code runs, I get the following log in my console:

```
2015-09-04 13:57:05.878 GoDriver[1050:415300] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x14f76130> on <GoDriver.LoginViewController: 0x14e37fd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Even though the visible view is the TripsTableViewController.

Comment: by any chance, do you have a different controller already presented ? If you have some presented controller, then that controller is replacing your view hierarchy and you can just use the presenting controller to present something different. You have to either dismiss first or present from the presented controller. That is, when A is presenting B, then you can't present C from A, you have to dismiss B or present C from B.

Comment: Or you can just find the current top-most controller and present on that (see the example I posted earlier).

Comment: Of what type is the root view controller and how is the `NavigationController` related to the root view controlller?

Comment: The root view controller is `UINavigationController`. `NavigationController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` and is the active root view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used code like this to present an alert over whatever controller is currently top-most. Maybe something like it would work for you?

```
- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    NSString *title = [error localizedDescription];
    NSString *message = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];

    // Find top-most controller
    UIViewController *viewController = [_window rootViewController];

    UIViewController *presentedViewController;
    do {
        presentedViewController = [viewController presentedViewController];

        if (presentedViewController != nil) {
            viewController = presentedViewController;
        }
    } while (presentedViewController != nil);

    // Display alert
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[mainBundle localizedStringForKey:@"application.ok"] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];

    [viewController presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This answer is almost correctly. In order for it to work, I had to change to a strategy of replacing the rootViewController when a user logs in instead of just using storyboard segues.

Comment: So if this is the answer, do I get the bounty?  ;-)

Comment: Sorry. Stupid StackOverflow wouldn't let me give the bounty until 5 minutes after marking the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you presented `UINavigationController` on top of `LoginViewController` that's why `rootViewController` of `window` which is `LoginViewController` as per storyboard and its view is not loaded on window.

I created extension on `UIApplication` to get the `visiableViewControler`

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func visibleViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return visibleViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController

            if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController where top.view.window != nil {
                return visibleViewController(top)
            } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return visibleViewController(selected)
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return visibleViewController(presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

Now you need to get the `visiableViewController` from `rootViewController` of `window` and present your alertView on that viewController.

```
let visiableViewController = UIApplication.visibleViewController(rootViewController)
visiableViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

We did something like this in the app delegate,

```
BOOL viewLoaded = navController.topViewController.isViewLoaded;
            if (viewLoaded)
            {
                [navController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                self.showDeepLink = true;
            }
```

Then in the main activity

```
if (delegate.showDeepLink)
    {
        delegate.showDeepLink = false;
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Where does the `navController` come from?

Comment: CustomNavController *navController = (CustomNavController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;

Comment: When I try to use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController` it also returns `LoginViewController` even though I'm seeing the `NavigationController` with the `TripsTableViewController` on screen.